# Spring Boot 2 Custom Actuator Endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Noob: OK. I start with a STS Spring Starter Project / Maven / Java 8 / Spring Boot 2.0, and select the Web and Actuator dependencies. It builds and runs fine, and reponds to http://localhost:8080/actuator/health. I add an "Endpoint" to the main application class, so that it looks like this.

```
package com.thumbsup;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.ReadOperation;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Selector;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class YourStash11Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourStash11Application.class, args);
    }

    @Endpoint(id="mypoint")
    public class CustomPoint {
        @ReadOperation
        public String getHello(){
            return "Hello" ;
        }
    }

}
```

I try to enable everything in application.properties:

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.endpoint.conditions.enabled=true
management.endpoint.mypoint.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

But when it builds, there's no reference to mapping /actuator/mypoint, and
http://localhost:8080/actuator/mypoint and
http://localhost:8080/application/mypoint
both return 404 errors.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

OK, solved:

```
    @Endpoint(id="mypoint")
    @Component
    public class myPointEndPoint {
        @ReadOperation
        public String mypoint(){
            return "Hello" ;
        }
    }
```

What was missing was the "@Component" annotation. But, where is this in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

The initial partly problem was that the code did not add an endpoint with no "selector"

[Source](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0)

```
@Endpoint(id = "loggers")
@Component
public class LoggersEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public Map<String, Object> loggers() { ... }

    @ReadOperation
    public LoggerLevels loggerLevels(@Selector String name) { ... }

    @WriteOperation
    public void configureLogLevel(@Selector String name, LogLevel configuredLevel) { ... }

}
```

> This endpoint exposes three operations:
>
> GET on /application/loggers: the configuration of all loggers (as it
>   has no "selector" parameter):
>
> GET on /application/loggers/{name}: the configuration of a named
>   logger (using the name @Selector).
>
> ...

The edited question led to the conclusion [that it should be a bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-custom)

> If you add a @Bean annotated with @Endpoint, any methods annotated
>   with @ReadOperation, @WriteOperation, or @DeleteOperation are
>   automatically exposed over JMX and, in a web application, over HTTP as
>   well. Endpoints can be exposed over HTTP using Jersey, Spring MVC, or
>   Spring WebFlux.

Or see [comments in the announcement of the feature](https://spring.io/blog/2017/08/22/introducing-actuator-endpoints-in-spring-boot-2-0#comment-3481606304)

Comment: Alas, adding "/aname", "?name=aname" to the URL, or removing the @Selector reference entirely had no effect.

Comment: I updated to answer your updated question with a reference to the documentation where it is stated that is should be a bean.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help somebody.

Looks like `@ReadOperation` doesn't support return type `Void`. You should return at least an empty string on your `invoke` method.

spring-boot 2.0.3.RELEASE

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "heartbeat")
public class HeartbeatEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public String invoke() {
        return "";
    }
}
```